# Proof - Homomorphic Image of Group Element is Coset - Fraleigh p. 135 13.52, p.130 Theorem 13.15

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification

[Theorem 13.15](http://www.proofwiki.org/w/index.php?title=Homomorphic_Image_of_Group_Element_is_Coset&oldid=174775): Let $\phi: G \rightarrow G'$ be a group homomorphism, $g \in G$.
Then $g\ker\phi = (\ker\phi)g = \operatorname{Im}^{-1} \left[ \; \{ \; \phi(g) \; \} \; \right] = \phi^{-1}[ \; \{ \; \phi(g) \; \} \;] = \{ \; x \in G : \phi(x) = \phi(g) \; \} \; (☼)$
Consequently, the two
partitions of G into left cosets and into right cosets of H are the same.

> (1.) By means of definition of preimage, $\phi^{-1}[ \text{ any set } S] = \{ x\in S:\phi(x) \in S\} $
>   Hence shouldn't $\phi^{-1}[ \; \color{magenta}{\{ \, \phi(g) \, \}} \;] = \{ \; x \in \color{magenta}{\{ \, \phi(g) \, \}} : \phi(x) \in \color{magenta}{\{ \, \phi(g) \, \}}\; \}$?
>   What does this really mean?

[Prove $(\ker\phi)g =  \{ \; x \in G : \phi(x) = \phi(g) \; \}$](http://users.humboldt.edu/pgoetz/Homework%20Solutions/Math%20343/hw12solns.pdf)

♥ **Forward Step ♥ Prove Subset:** Let $\color{red}{y \in (\ker\phi)g} \iff y = kg$ for some $k \in \ker\phi$.
$\implies \color{red}{\phi(y) = \phi(kg)=\phi(g)} \iff y \in \{ \; x \in G : \phi(x) = \phi(g) \; \}. ♥$

> (2.) How does this prove $y \in \{ \; x \in G : \phi(x) = \phi(g) \; \}$?
>   We only proved $\color{red}{y \in (\ker\phi)g \implies \phi(y) = \phi(g)}$?

♥ **Backward Step ♥ Superset:** Let $x \in \{ \; x \in G : \phi(x) = \phi(g) \; \}$.
Then $\phi(x) = \phi(g) \iff \phi(xg^{-1}) =$ identity of G'.  $\iff xg^{-1} \in \ker\phi \iff x \in (\ker\phi)g. ♥$

Answer (score 0):

You showed that an arbitrary element $y$ in the coset of the kernel is one of the "$x$'s" that have the same image under $\phi$ as $g$ does. In this case, "$x$" is just a dummy variable, any symbol could have been used, whereas $g$ stands for some specific element of $G$.